# Microblink SDK: Take only the photo which is inside rectangle

Tags: reactjs, microblink

I am using Microblink Sdk with reactjs. So, when I open the camera to take the photo of some document it takes the picture of whole frame not just inside the reactange.

[image]

Is there any option to take only the picture only inside the rectangle.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rectangle displayed on the screen is there to help the user position the document they are scanning.
Specifically, the detection of the document and data extraction works best if the entire image is sent to processing, and if the document is positioned roughly around the rectangle.

That means that if you “cropped” the image to the rectangle before recognition, you would effectively lower the success rate of scanning or you would have to move the camera further away from the document to keep it in that sweet spot where the document has a margin around it, resulting in a lower resolution image, lowering the success rate once more and defeating the purpose of the initial cropping.